# arranging the output in a different line

Tags: arrays, sorting, input

just a bit of polish work needed..

```
command = ""
names = []
while command != "exit"
puts 'please enter names seperated by a space: '

 command = gets.chomp!

 if command == "quit"
   names.sort! do|a,b| a.upcase <=> b.upcase end         # use {...} for do\end, in a single entry rather then multiple
    names.each_with_index do |name, index|
   if index % 2 == 0
       puts "#{name}", "\n"
      else
      puts "#{name.reverse}", "\n"
  end
 end
  else
    names << command
  end
end
```

so what this progam does is display a number of names that where entered by the user. what i cant get it to do is display the names under each other. eg.
rob
bill
lucy
chop
...
its then to display every second name backwards and to display them under like this

rob

bill

lucy

chop

======

llib

pohc.

lolmy brain is cooked any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it :

```
names = []
while true
  puts 'please enter names seperated by a space: '
  command = gets.chomp
  break if command == 'exit' #exit loop if exit is entered
  command.split(' ').each {|a| names.push(a)} # split up each word with space as delimiter and insert into the array
end


temp = []
names.each do |each| #cycle thru array
  puts each # print each entry
  temp.push(each) if names.index(each).odd? #if entry is odd then add to temp array
end
puts '======'
temp.each {|each| puts each.reverse} #print each entry reversed
```

I can try to fix yours if you want...